# isalnum equivalent using #define

Tags: c, casting, macros, alphanumeric

I am trying to determine if every character in my string is alphanumeric.  My compiler does not have the isalnum function.

My function is below and my_struct has a char array of size 6 (uint8 bom_pn[6]) ....and yes uint8 is a char.

```
boolean myfunc( my_struct * lh )
{
ret = ( isalphanum( lh->bom_pn ) && isalphanum( lh->bom_pn + 1 ) &&
        isalphanum( lh->bom_pn + 2 ) && isalphanum( lh->bom_pn + 3 ) &&
        isalphanum( lh->bom_pn + 4 ) && isalphanum( lh->bom_pn + 5 ) );
}
```

My macro definition is below:

```
#define isalphanum(c) ( ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) ||  \
                        ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) ||  \
                        ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) )
```

The above throws the error "operand types are incompatible (" uint8 * " and " int ")"

If I change my definition to the following, my code compiles and I get warnings.

```
#define isalphanum(c) ( ( (uint8)c >= '0' && (uint8)c <= '9' ) ||  \
                    ( (uint8)c >= 'A' && (uint8)c <= 'Z' ) ||  \
                    ( (uint8)c >= 'a' && (uint8)c <= 'z' ) )
```

Warning: "conversion from pointer to smaller integer"

My question is, how do I properly create this definition without warnings (and obviously check correctly).

Thanks

Comment: Note that, beyond your pointer vs. pointed-to issue, you are not handling locales at all.  Why does your environment not have `ctype.h`?

Comment: bah, i meant to just say return ( isal..... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said `lh->bom_pn` is an array of bytes, which means it is effectively a pointer.

So when you pass it to `isalphanum`, you're passing a pointer, and comparing it to literal bytes.

You have two options:

**1.)**

```
ret = ( isalphanum( lh->bom_pn[0] ) && isalphanum( lh->bom_pn[1] ) &&
        isalphanum( lh->bom_pn[2] ) && isalphanum( lh->bom_pn[3] ) &&
        isalphanum( lh->bom_pn[4] ) && isalphanum( lh->bom_pn[5] ) );
```

**2.)**

```
#define isalphanum(c) ( ( *(c) >= '0' && *(c) <= '9' ) ||  \
                        ( *(c) >= 'A' && *(c) <= 'Z' ) ||  \
                        ( *(c) >= 'a' && *(c) <= 'z' ) )
```

Either one should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response and detailed info.  funny how there are three different solutions from three users :)

Comment: again `*(c) >= 'A' && *(c) <= 'Z'` is OK if the character set is ASCII but is not OK in the general case (e.g., EBCDIC)

Answer (score 1):

Change all occurrences of

```
lh->bom_pn+i //pointer
```

to

```
lh->bom_pn[i] //character
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `bom_pn` is an array you need to pass it as `isalphanum(*lh->bom_pn )`,`isalphanum(*lh->bom_pn+i )` etc

Comment: ...And another way to fix it.  Thanks